# Website (HTML) Read Only Form Email Submission

Tags: php, html, css, forms, email

I got a website in testing, how it works is
Step 1) Form to key in Details in page1.php
Step 2) with the POST function, the keyed in form values appears in next page2.php in read only form format. Sort of like a summary of the information they keyed in. at the bottom they are to click "confirm" and an email is supposed to be sent with the full details of that page2.php.

My problem:
I can get it to sent email from page1.php, in the form page and send email upon clicking submit. but that is not what i want, i want it to send email after they confirm their details from page2.php. there is where i get the error.

my page2.php file has this as the code below. the form-to-email.php is the action to send email which works when its sent directly from a form but not from this page2.php read only page to confirm the details.

What am i doing wrong?

```
                <form action="form-to-email.php" method="post" class="box readonly">
                    <h3>Vehicle Details</h3>
                    <div class="f-row">
                        <div class="one-fourth">Type</div>
                        <div class="three-fourth">Transport Service</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="f-row">
                        <div class="one-fourth">Vehicle</div>
                        <div class="three-fourth">14 Foot Lorry</div>
                    </div>

                    <h3>Customer Details</h3>

                    <div class="f-row">
                        <div class="one-fourth">Name</div>
                        <div class="three-fourth"><?php $name = $_POST["name"]; echo $name; ?></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="f-row">
                        <div class="one-fourth">Phone</div>
                        <div class="three-fourth"><?php $name = $_POST["number"]; echo $name; ?></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="f-row">
                        <div class="one-fourth" label for='email'>Email</div>
                        <div class="three-fourth"><?php $name = $_POST["email"]; echo $name; ?></div>
                    </div>

                    <h3>Job Details</h3>
                    <div class="f-row">
                        <div class="one-fourth">Date</div>
                        <div class="three-fourth"><?php $name = $_POST["date"]; echo $name; ?></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="f-row">
                        <div class="one-fourth">Time</div>
                        <div class="three-fourth"><?php $name = $_POST["time"]; echo $name; ?></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="f-row">
                        <div class="one-fourth">Pick Up</div>
                        <div class="three-fourth"><?php $name = $_POST["pick"]; echo $name; ?></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="f-row">
                        <div class="one-fourth">Drop Off</div>
                        <div class="three-fourth"><?php $name = $_POST["drop"]; echo $name; ?></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="f-row">
                        <div class="one-fourth">Items</div>
                        <div class="three-fourth"><?php $name = $_POST["items"]; echo $name; ?></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="f-row">
                        <div class="one-fourth">Remarks</div>
                        <div class="three-fourth"><?php $name = $_POST["remarks"]; echo $name; ?></div>
                    </div>

                    <h3 align="center">TOTAL: $80 SGD</h3><input type="submit" class="btn medium color" value="Confirm (Cash Payment)"></form>
```

help.

Comment: post from page 1 to 2. then page 2 posts to he mailing script including what it got from page 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you don't have any inputs in `<form>` on `page2.php`. So what you submit is empty.

There are at least 2 ways to solve it:

---

1 - Store your values in `php session`:

Add the following lines at top of your `page2.php` script:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['post_values'] = $_POST;
   ...
?>
```

And the following lines at top of your `form-to-email.php`:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $_POST = $_SESSION['post_values'];
   $_SESSION['post_values'] = array(); // this will clear the values, so they wouldn't get resubmitted on page refresh. You could probably use `unset($_SESSION['post_values'])` but that sometimes doesn't work, so it's safer to redefine it as empty array.
   ...
?>
```

Storing values in `php session` will allow you to pass those values to other scripts in same domain. Please note that every time you want to use `$_SESSION` object, you got to start session first with `session_start()`. This has to be done **before** outputting anything.

---

2 - Add hidden inputs to your code like this (for every field):

```
   <div class="f-row">
      <div class="one-fourth">Name</div>
      <div class="three-fourth"><input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php json_encode($_POST["name"]);?>/><?php echo $_POST["name"];?></div>
   </div>

   <div class="f-row">
      <div class="one-fourth">Phone</div>
      <div class="three-fourth"><input type="hidden" name="number" value="<?php json_encode($_POST["number"]);?>/><?php echo $_POST["number"];?></div>
   </div>

   ... etc.
```

That will create invisible inputs so the values could be send again. Please note that I am using `json_encode()` function so it wouldn't break the HTML syntax if value would contain for example `"`.